# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined while fetching VANILLA JS

Tags: javascript, dictionary

When I launch `splitArray(people, 5)` and `displayContent(0)` functions one after another in console, they work perfectly fine, but when I add them with `.then()` into my fetch method, I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` error.

I'm trying to make my first app that displays JSON file as a table with pagination, sorting methods etc. I've searched for answers here but every thread I've found seems to be about REACT. I'm trying to do this with pure vanilla js.

```
const endpoint = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/agowj';
let people = [];
let peeps = [];
fetch(endpoint)
  .then(blob => blob.json())
  .then(data => people.push(...data))
  .then(splitArray(people, 5))
  .then(displayContent(0));

function displayContent(page) {
  let suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');
  let html = peeps[page].map(person => {
    return `
    <tr>
    <td>${person.id}</td>
    <td>${person.firstName}</td>
    <td>${person.lastName}</td>
    <td>${person.dateOfBirth}</td>
    <td>${person.function}</td>
    <td>${person.experience}</td>
    </tr>
    `}).join("");
    suggestions.innerHTML = html;
  };

  function splitArray(arr, size) {
  peeps = [];
  for (i=0; i < arr.length; i += size){
    peeps.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
  }
  return peeps;
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: This: `.then(splitArray(people, 5))` calls `splitArray()` *before* calling `.then()`, passing the returned value. You have to wrap those calls in functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the result of these methods to `then`. You need to pass a function instead:

```
.then(() => splitArray(people, 5))
.then(() => displayContent(0));
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!